# Free alternative to SQLAPI++?

Tags: c++, database, api

Are there any free (and maybe open source) alternatives to [SQLAPI++](http://www.sqlapi.com/)? This library looks very good but it is not free.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look at the [CppCMS](http://cppcms.sourceforge.net/wikipp/en/page/main) project which has the [CppDB library](http://cppcms.sourceforge.net/sql/cppdb/index.html).

Comment: also looks pretty nice. thank you.

Comment: do you know by any chance how to build this lib on a mac. I am getting this error: `error: size of array ‘assert_on_sqlwchar_is_16’ is negative`. thanx

Comment: @miki725 I don't know. I believe you can contact the author at the [support page](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=209965&%0Aatid=1011835).

Comment: is this support ORACLE Database?

Comment: Id rather try to use the SQL Server Native ODBC driver but CodeBlocks is giving me fits with it. I guess it's just a matter of one #include statement with visual studio.